# Multiple hypothesis testing for Chi-square

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons

I am writing an article in which I am testing simultaneously multiple hypotheses  involving two concepts:

> 1) Quality and 2) Gender
>
> But as the quality is a more complex concept I present it as 2 smaller
>   sub-concepts:
>
> 1.1. Quality of the products (QP)
>
> 1.2. Quality of the services (QS)
>
> Each of those 2 smaller concepts I measure with 10 variables.
>
> In the end, for the QS I find that only for 2 variables differ across
>   male and female. As my research hypothesis is that QS is different across
>   people of different genders, can I claim that the hypothesis is
>   partially confirmed as at least for one variable of QS it was the
>   same? Is there a typical solution in research about this or should I
>   completely reject my hypothesis as for the majority of the variables
>   no differences were found between genders?
>
> I have pretty much the same results for the QS, and I do not know how
>   to interpret them. Should I confirm, reject or partially confirm the overall/joint hypothesis? Can you suggest me some useful references?

Comment: Please remember to use a p-value correction when working with multiple comparison in order to avoid false positives

Comment: Yes, I have already done this, David. Thank you very much.

Comment: In that case you can confirm that QS is indeed different! That's the precise reason why the corrections are used

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest me, please a reference to refer to. I read that it is called the coherence principle in multiple hypotheses testing but I cannot find an article to justify my conclusion;

Comment: Bonferroni, C. E., Teoria statistica delle classi e calcolo delle probabilità, Pubblicazioni del R Istituto Superiore di Scienze Economiche e Commerciali di Firenze 1936

Comment: Thank you very much David!